# What will be if I use libaio + fsync()?

Tags: io, aio, fsync

I know that when I write files using `write()` + `fsync()` (or `O_SYNC` + `write()`, I think they are same [ref #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828666/what-is-the-difference-between-o-direct-o-sync-write-and-o-direct-wr) [ref #2](https://github.com/ronomon/direct-io)), it means I am using blocking synchronous I/O, and the if the `write()`(with `O_SYNC`) or `fsync()` returns, it means the data is safely on the device medium (e.g., TLC NAND for SSD) rather than the device cache (e.g., DDRAM in SSD).

While what if I use `libaio`? (because I want to make sure the write issued by libaio is on the storage medium rather than the device cache. i.e., I suppose when `io_getevents()` returns, it may not make sure the write is on the storage medium, and it may just on the device cache)

- **Question 1**: does `fsync()` exclusively works for synchronous I/O?
- **Question 2**：is `fsync()` after `io_submit()` an undefined behavior?
- **Question 3**: how to make asynchronous write safely persisted to the device medium rather than device cache (no battery-backed cache).

Comment: It seems that linux does not support aio fsync currently: https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-3.25/engines/libaio.c#L256-L268

Comment: And if one wants to safely persistent write with libaio, using `RWF_SYNC` flag in `io_submit(2)`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/io_submit.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer is only looking at things from Linux perspective. Other operating systems may have different behaviour/semantics)

So long as you wait for any outstanding asynchronous I/O to be completed you will be able to then send down your `fsync()` and know all previous I/O was written to stable storage to the best knowledge of the Linux kernel<sup>*</sup>.

> does fsync() exclusively works for synchronous I/O?

This question doesn't make sense. `fsync()` works on I/O that Linux has agreed has been "sent" and then also flushes the device cache. If you asynchronously send an I/O to the kernel, has the kernel agreed it has been "sent"? Also see the answer to final question...

> is fsync() after io_submit() an undefined behavior?

Technically [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) would mean from then on ANYTHING would be allowed to legally happen (e.g. so called nasal daemons). That's not the case here  but I think you are asking your first question so the answer there still holds.

> how to make asynchronous write safely persisted to the device medium rather than device cache (no battery-backed cache).

If you're stuck using `libaio` you could manually build a barrier by waiting for all outstanding I/O to be completed and then sending an `fsync()` and waiting for that or ([as mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073136/what-will-be-if-i-use-libaio-fsync/66098696#comment116837020_66073136)). Another `libaio` technique is to set the `RWF_SYNC` flag during `io_submit()`. If you were using [`io_uring`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57451551/2732969) you would have another option because you can use its chaining and it has an asynchronous `fsync` operation (`IORING_OP_FSYNC`).

---

<sup>*</sup> I'm excluding the cases where errors happen because they are rather more complicated. See [Writing programs to cope with I/O errors causing lost writes on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434872/writing-programs-to-cope-with-i-o-errors-causing-lost-writes-on-linux) for a detailed explaintion.

Comment: In the other answer, you mentioned: "With direct I/O io_submit() does not return until all its requests have been allocated and queued at the block layer level." In that case, is it still necessary to manually build a barrier before calling `fsync()`?

Comment: @sayap **Yes** because how else do you know the `fsync()` won't overtake the submitted I/Os and return before they do? Just because you've queued some items you need another guarantee that re-ordering won't take at any level before your `fsync()` completes. If you were somehow guarantee the kernel would never re-order submitted commands (how?) I can just turn around and ask "how do you guarantee the disk controller won't re-order the commands"?